# How Can I Map IIS on My PC with Static IP to my Domain Name?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, web-hosting, dns-hosting

Now I have got an internet connection with Static Ip.

I want to know How can I map my website to my Static IP(Received from ISP).

I know this is not a good Idea for Security and Performance issues, But just Wanted to know as I can set up a test Project.

Again, Can't I just by a domain name and map it to my Static Ip, instead of buying them from WebHosting Providers. Now I have bought the space from bizzhost and hosted my site by setting the Name Server.

Thanks,
Subhen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your ISP gives you access to a DNS control panel you would just need to update your A record to point to your new static IP.  Check with your host for exact details on how to do it since every control panel is slightly different.

Allow 48 hours for changes to take affect since DNS replication takes time.

Comment: DNS doesn't replicate, it caches. It caches for the life of the TTL in question, not 48 hours. If there's no existing record (A or CNAME record) for the web site then there will be no TTL to expire and the site will be available immediately. If there is a current record then only those hosts which have the old record in their DNS cache will have to wait until the TTL expires before they'll get the new information, from a new lookup.

Comment: A bad choice of phrase - I should have said propagate. Your details are of course correct - based on the question is sounded like he had a domain already. I plucked the 48 hours as a rough guide since from experience most people new to this get confused when the don't see an instant result from a change and I wanted to keep the answer simple given that it sounds like DNS is all very new to him.

Comment: They don't really propagate either. They don't get "pushed" anywhere. They get cached by DNS resolvers that ask for the records, which is a pull operation. Anyhoo, I know what you meant but just wanted to clarify it to avoid any confusion. No offense intended and none taken I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a domain name yet or not? If not, you'll need to purchase one. You can purchase one from any domain name vendor you wish, but I recommend using one of the larger ones like Network Solutions or GoDaddy. Once you've purchased a domain name you'll need to set up your DNS records with whomever is going to host your DNS namespace, I recommend using the vendor that you purchase the domain name from. Then you'll need to set up port forwarding on your firewall\router to allow HTTP traffic to get to your internal host.

Comment: I have already my personal Site up and running at , http://www.subhendu.info, While dig into DNS settings , itsays Record Type , ptr and Then in the Ptr field , has some IP.

There are other things like Record Type : NS,A,CName,NX,TXT,SRV ... Mostly I have to change the PTR , but what the other fields does mean?

Answer (score 0):

i use www.cloudns.net for a DNS provider and works good!